# Smalltalk, newline character

Tags: tokenize, smalltalk

Does anybody know what's the newline delimiter for a string in smalltalk?

I'm trying to split a string in separate lines, but I cannot figure out what's the newline character in smalltalk.

ie.

```
string := 'smalltalk is 
           a lot of fun.
           ok, it's not.'

I need to split it in:
line1: smalltalk is
line2: a lot of fun.
line3: ok, it's not.
```

I can split a line based on any letter or symbol, but I can't figure out what the newline delimter is.

OK here is how I'm splitting the string based on commas, but I cannot do it based on a new line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The newline delimiter is typically the carriage return, i.e., `Character cr`, or as others mentioned, in a string, `String cr`.  If you wanted to support all standard newline formats, just include both standard delimiters, for example:

```
string := 'smalltalk is
a lot of fun.'.

string findTokens: String cr, String lf.
```

Since you now mention you're using VisualWorks, the above won't work unless you have the "squeak-accessing" category loaded (which you probably won't unless you're using Seaside).  You could use a regular expression match instead:

```
'foo
bar' allRegexMatches: '[^', (String with: Character cr), ']+'
```

Comment: So you can also set "sep" to (String with: Character cr) as above.  Please mention you're using VW in future, Smalltalk dialects differ substantially as you've discovered.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. String with: Character cr worked perfectly. I will make sure I mention VW in the future. THanks again.

Comment: Hi, This is too old but allRegexMatches message doesn't seem to be working in current VisualWorks version.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't use VW any more. It worked at the time (which in retrospect I should have documented which VW version I was using!)

Comment: in some commands the traditional c char is required '\n' in lieu of cr. Also $<10> shows up in review & means the same.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution (I don't know if it is the better) is:

|array |
array := mystring findTokens: String cr

Where String cr is the carriage return character

Comment: findTokens is not defined. I'm using visual works, I don't know if that would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881666/new-line-in-squeak): `Character cr`.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it didn't work. Well actually it kept running forever. I had to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the String>>withCRs message then delimit the carriage returns with backslashes, thus--

string := 'smalltalk is\ 
           a lot of fun.\
           ok, it's not.' withCRs.

Comment: (Works in VW and squeak both)

Answer (score 0):

It is of course depending on the encoding. Could be cr, lf or crlf. For unicode there are a few extra possibilities. See: [pharo linesDo:](http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=1356)